# Getting error as "method chrome() is undefined for the type DesiredCapabilities"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, desiredcapabilities

Context: Getting error as method chrome undefined from the below code:

```
package zapSeleniumIntegration;

import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class BrowserDriverFactory {

    static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriver createChromeDriver(Proxy proxy, String path) {
    // Set proxy in the chrome browser
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();//Getting error as method chrome undefined
            capabilities.setCapability("127.0.0.1", 8080);
            // Set system property for chrome driver with the path
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\kotla.naveen\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.merge(capabilities);
            return new ChromeDriver(options); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> The old method Capabilities is deprecated. 
>   Use ChromeOptions object and passed it to the `ChromeDriver()` constructor. Also, you don't need to use  `options.merge(capabilities);` instead, you can use `options.setCapability(params, params)`

**However, You can completely skip DesiredCapabilities and use only ChromeOptions with setCapability method as mentioned below:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
```

**//Set the pre defined capability – ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS value to true:**

```
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
```

**//Pass the chromeoption object to the ChromeDriver:**

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

************** **To set proxy** **************

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setAutodetect(false);
proxy.setHttpProxy("proxy_url:port"); 
proxy.setSslProxy("proxy_url:port");
proxy.setNoProxy("no_proxy-var");

options.setCapability("proxy", proxy); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line instead :
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();